# Meteor as dependency in npm module? Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/mongo'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have 2 meteor projects which share models. I'd like to consolidate the model schemas into an NPM private module.

My module contains this code:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { packageSchema } from './schema';

export const Packages = new Mongo.Collection('packages');
Packages.attachSchema(packageSchema);

export default Packages;
```

When I install this NPM module in my parent meteor project and start the server, I get the following error on the first line of this file:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/mongo'
```

What is the correct way to install/reference meteor in an NPM module? (It cannot be added as a standard NPM dependency.)

Comment: The `meteor/*` syntax is Meteor's convention to map to an atmosphere package - considering your package is not a Meteor app, you aren't going to have that available to you. Perhaps you can change this module to be an atmosphere package instead of npm until [the full transition to npm occurs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/Roadmap.md#full-transition-to-npm).

Comment: Thanks. I actually started this as an atmosphere package installed as a git submodule but trying to move to NPM because there doesn't seem to be a clean way to use atmosphere packages & git submodules with heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules). Am I mistaken?

Comment: I tend to avoid git submodules, and don't have experience with heroku, but... you might be able to have your package as a local project that is symlinked. Then just `meteor add <yourpackage>` from the main project (making some assumptions about your project structure)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a way to include meteor in my NPM module. Instead, I put the code in an Atmosphere package and used the `git subtree` methods to include it in both projects. (This avoided known issues with submodules and symlinks.)